# Parameter checking in library hierarchies

Tags: c, parameters, parent-child

When writing function libraries, is there a consensus on whether function parameters should be checked in a child library if they have already been checked in the parent? By way of illustration, consider the following code fragment:

```
uint8 er_remove(DE_LIST *deque)
{
    ER_OBJECT *object;
    uint8 result = ER_BAD_ARGUMENT;

    if (deque != NULL)
    {
        result = de_remove_first(deque, (void **)&object);
    }

    return result;
}
```

Given that the function `de_remove_first()` also checks the `deque` parameter to see if it is NULL or not, is it considered good form to check it again in `er_remove()`?

From a functional point of view, the check in `er_remove()` is clearly not necessary. It does however make obvious to the reader that `deque` parameter is checked, and it also removes the reliance on the check in `de_remove_first()` remaining in place in future code revisions.

Any thoughts?

Comment: In general the function requiring a condition is the place to verify it. See preconditions, postconditions, invariants.

Comment: They are not concepts I have come across before - thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the library function.

All the functions that are documented as part of the external interface to the library — the functions that users call — should validate their arguments stringently (or, at least, consider doing so).

The functions that are internal to the library, functions called only by functions within the library, do not need to do extra checking on their arguments — unless there is a condition that only that function can check.  The gateway (interface) functions should have validated their arguments, so the internal functions do not need to revalidate them.  You might still do checking in the internal functions with assertions, so that if a function miscalls one of the internal functions, you spot this during development.  But those assertions should <s>never</s> very seldom fire.

Comment: That sounds like a very sensible approach. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

No, you don't.

`er_remove` is simply passing that parameter through to another function. The logic using `deque` is totally implemented inside `de_remove_first` in your case, the only one who has the responsibility to make that check.

If you do that again in `de_remove_first`, you make two functions both bound to the value of that parameter. It sounds like an overkill. If in future, `de_remove_first` is optimized and can accept a NULL pointer, what will happen to `er_removed`?

```
uint8 er_remove(DE_LIST *deque)
{
    ER_OBJECT *object;
    uint8 result = ER_BAD_ARGUMENT;

    // Will you remember to remove this kind of checks?
    if (deque != NULL)
    {
         // OK, I am now acceptable to a NULL "deque".
         result = de_remove_first(deque, (void **)&object);
    }

    return result;
}
```

The best case is that it reminds you of this extra check. You find all such checks along the calling path, and get them removed. The worst is that you forget to update it and the code that accepts a NULL parameter in `de_remove_first` just gets bypassed and will never be executed.

Another benefit is that your caller don't have to check this parameter everytime they call `er_remove` or `de_remove_first`, thus simpfying their code. What if `free` was designed like this? Think about it.

```
// Check NULL whenever you call free to release a piece of memory
if (ptr != NULL)
{
   free(ptr);
}
```